# core data search for attributes with same values

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a core data db with attributes like "size" and "filename" in the entity "files".

I want to write a predicate that will search in the db and return elements with identical "size" attribute and "name" attribute so to get a list of all duplicate files (assuming that two or more files with the same name and the same size are good candidates to be indeed identical).

I thought this would be a super easy predicate, but can't find reference to the correct statement to make.

This is what i did so far, but is extremely inefficient (O(n2)) as it uses the fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects instead of doing the search and filtering on the sqllite db.

```
records = [_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
 for (int i = 0; i < records - 1; i++) { 
        NSIndexPath *indexI = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i  inSection:0];
        NSManagedObject *objecti = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexI];

        for (int j = i+1; j < records; j++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexJ = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:0];
            NSManagedObject *objectj = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexJ];

            if ([[objecti valueForKey:@"filename"] isEqualToString: [objectj valueForKey:@"filename"]]
                && [[objecti valueForKey:@"sizeReadable"] isEqualToString: [objectj valueForKey:@"sizeReadable"]])
            {
                NSLog(@"Dupe found");
                NSLog(@"iDupe is %@", [objecti valueForKey: @"filename"]);
                NSLog(@"iDupe size is %@", [objecti valueForKey: @"sizeReadable"]);
                NSLog(@"jDupe is %@", [objectj valueForKey: @"filename"]);
                NSLog(@"jDupe is %@", [objectj valueForKey: @"sizeReadable"]);

            }
```

I'm sure that there is a better way with a predicate but can't find it.

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks,
      dom

Comment: In addition to @PanayotPanayotov's very relevant question, also understand that an `NSFetchRequest` returns an `NSArray` of results. Therefore, if the count of that returned array is greater than 1, you should then check for duplicates.

Comment: Hi, I am looking at something similar to this sql query:

Comment: "select filename from files group by filename having count(*) >1" to be done with NSPredicate. Does NSPredicate have the "count" keyword ? or something similar ? This is what I'm looking for. Thanks !